# Why does nginx reverse_proxy on my react app return a 404 when searching a path?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have an nginx server with a reverse proxy pointing to my react app. The page loads fine and the links to different paths work fine when pressing through the page. However when I manually type out the url with path, I get a 404 error. Its the same path as via clicking links but I get a 404.

Here's my nginx conf file:

```
server{

    listen 443 ssl; 
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name sub.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    // I tried adding an explicit path:
    location /about{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/about;
    }
    //
    // SSL Cert stuff here...
    //
}
```

I have a similar issue with my nodejs on reverse proxy where the main url works fine but anything with a path returns a 502, but thats a separate question.

Comment: Do you have http to https redirect enabled?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had to update my nginx config to this:

```
server{

listen 443 ssl; 
listen [::]:443 ssl;
server_name sub.*;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    // I have to route each of my paths to my servers root
    location /about{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    location /contact{
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    // ...etc

    //
    // SSL Cert stuff here...
    //
}
```

However this solution is a pain so I will be pursuing a different hosting strategy altogether.